# Sql query tbl comment

Tags: sql, self-join

```
Comment:tbl

CommentId PK  
CommentEntry  
CommentDate  
Category  
CommentCommentId  
BlogEntryId FK


Insert into Comment(CommentId, CommentEntry, CommentDate, Category, CommentCommentId, BlogEntryId)
Values("1","I love shoes","10-3-2011","1","" ,"13"),
("2","I love shoes too","10-4-2011","1","1" ,"13"),
("3","There nice shoes in the mall","2","","13");
```

QUESTION:Produce, for the first comment made on a given Blog entry, any further comments made on that original comment only. The user should be prompted for the Blog entry’s unique identifier.

ANS SUPPOSE TO BE :

```
("1","I love shoes","10-3-2011","1","" ,"13"),
("2","I love shoes too","10-4-2011","1","1" ,"13")
```

### Please help with sql

I want to be to do a self join to accept [BlogEntryId] and product 1st Comment 'CommentCommentId=""' and all the Comments on that 1st comment .

help with sql please:)

Comment: This isn't at all clear. Can you try rephrasing some things?

Comment: no such thing as a "inner left join", self or otherwise...

Comment: i tried    SQL QUERY : SELECT CommentId, CommentEntry, CommentDate, EmailAddress
FROM Comment
WHERE BlogEntryId = [?Blog Entry]
AND CommentCommentId = (SELECT CommentId 
FROM Comment
WHERE CommentDate = (SELECT min(CommentDate)
from Comment));

But its only returning: ("2","I love shoes too","10-4-2011","1","1" ,"13")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a bit to your original query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Comment 
WHERE BlogEntryId = [?Blog Entry] 
AND (
    CommentId = (SELECT CommentId FROM Comment WHERE CommentDate = (SELECT min(CommentDate) from Comment))
    OR
    CommentCommentId = (SELECT CommentId FROM Comment WHERE CommentDate = (SELECT min(CommentDate) from Comment))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
select * 
from comment c
join comment subc on c.commentcommentid = subc.commentid
where c.commentid = @inputID
```

This is a self join.

I think the answer to the homework question is simply this:

```
select *
from comment
where commentcommentid = @inputid
```